# SVN is not commiting my selenium code even after clean up

Tags: svn

SVN is not committing my selenium code even after clean up. I am getting below error on committing;

Problem running log

```
svn: Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with 

'D:\Users\vbehl\wspsc\SeleniumRepositoryProject', work item 265 (file-remove Browser_Files/IEDriverServer.exe)
Access is denied.  
svn: Can't remove file 'D:\Users\vbehl\wspsc\SeleniumRepositoryProject\Browser_Files\IEDriverServer.exe': Access is denied.  

Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted

Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted
```

Comment: Is the process `IEDriverServer.exe` still running? Did you try to kill it?

Comment: In addition to what @reto said Committing, by default, doesn't delete files. There could be an issue with the pre or post commit hooks in your environment.